# Tomcat 404 Error when deploying a WAR file of a REST web app

Tags: rest, tomcat, struts2, http-status-code-404

As part of a course in my CS undergrad degree I need to implement a RESTful web app using Struts2 framework. To do so I'm trying to first see an example of a working example of such a project.

I have downloaded such an example from the official Struts2 website in the following link under the title example applications - https://struts.apache.org/download.cgi.
after extracting the zip file, I saw the folder contained the relevant WAR file named struts2-rest-showcase.
Then, after installing Tomcat 10, I used Tomcat's Web Application Manager to deploy this WAR.

After deployment whenever I try starting the application I get HTTP Status 404 - Not Found error with the following error details:

Type - Status report

Message - The requested resource [/struts2-rest-showcase/] is not available

Description- The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

A similar error message occurred when I tried running another example, in the following link, using Tomcat through Eclipse IDE -
https://github.com/amolghotankar/struts2-rest-sample

I feel completely lost since the above examples are supposed to be working examples.

Comment: This is unclear question. With the information provided is not possible to give you any reasonable solution. 404 error code means that the resource you trying access via URL the server is not able to return because it either doesn't work or it's not exist. Check the server logs for real issue. Isn't that learned in CS educational institute?

Comment: Ditto--checking the server logs is the place to start;  it's impossible to know what may or may not be happening. Another approach would be to work in reverse: Make the smallest servlet app that could possibly work to vet your deploy process then add the smallest S2 app that could possibly work.

Comment: Starting w/ a complete example is more helpful when there's enough background knowledge to diagnose problems. Without that background knowledge it can be overwhelming.